# successfully using applyTransform() in Rniftyreg

Tags: r

I cant find a suitable format to get `applyTransform()` to bite.

`applyTransform(transform, sourceImageorMatrix)`
Cannot find a good format for `sourceImageorMatrix` that the function will like
I keep getting the error:

> "Object to transform should be a suitable image or matrix of points"

I've tried `as.matrix`, `as.cimg`, `image(as.matrix())`, and of course the matrix itself, however, `applyTransform` keeps shooting me down.

```
library(oro.nifti)
library(RNiftyReg)
library(jpeg)
library(mmand)
library(Thermimage)
library(imager)
library(raster)
library(opencv)




affine.path <- 'c:/pathtoaffines/'
image.path <- "c:'pathtoimages/"
source('image reg functions.R')


############################# get affines and determine the mean ###########################
Astart <- 1748
Aend <- 2198

goodsults <- list(1:55)


index <- 1
for (filenum in Astart:Aend){
    affine.file <- paste0(affine.path, 'AffineMatrixFor_',filenum,'.nii')
    if (file.exists(affine.file)){
        goodsults[[index]] <- readAffine(affine.file)
        index  <- index + 1
    }
}

mean.ft <- goodsults[[1]]

for (i in 2:43){
    mean.ft <- mean.ft + goodsults[[i]]
}
mean.ft <- mean.ft/length(goodsults)

################## apply the mean to an image that didnt get mapped right #########################

testflnum <- 1734  #good image
testflnum2 <- 1750  # bad image



psource <- get.IR(testflnum, image.path)

#im.targetNumber <- load.image(paste0(image.path,'FLIR',testflnum + 1, '.jpg'))
#im.targetcg <- grayscale(crop.borders(im.targetNumber, nx = 250, ny = 120))


im.targetNumber2 <- load.image(paste0(image.path, 'FLIR',testflnum + 1, '.jpg'))
im.targetcg2 <- grayscale(crop.borders(im.targetNumber2, nx = 250, ny = 120))
#result <- niftyreg(source, t(as.matrix(im.targetcg2)),nLevels = 8, init = mean.ft)


new.s <- applyTransform(mean.ft, psource)




#get.IR reads an FLIR IR photo and returns a matrix of pixel values of size   # 348 x 464
```

The expected result is a transformed matrix representing the 'bad' image (or the one that didnt get mapped right to begin with.

The error I am getting is:

> Error in applyTransform(mean.ft, w) : 
>   Object to transform should be a suitable image or matrix of points

Comment: Thanks for the edits!

Comment: So, I went ahead and just saved all of the images I wanted to transform, and sent them over to python where I was able to do so fairly trivially, then, after saving those as jpeg's moved them back in with R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it a lot easier to perform the transforms on my image set in Python, and then just move that set back to R to do everything else. Problem solved: use python.